# Webklex/Laravel-imap: Move email to trash

Tags: laravel, email, imap

How do I move my e-mails deleted in the Webklex Laravel imap package to the trash.
deletion is running. But I can't move. When I make the folder dd, I only see the INBOX path.

```
$oMessage->moveToFolder('Trash');
$oMessage->delete();
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find @mohamedruzaik

Comment: moveToFolder has been replaced to move you can check their document if you want and still it's not working

Answer (score 0):

1. Some IMAP servers don't support MOVE and UID MOVE IMAP commands, which are used by the move() method of this library. You can try to use the legacy protocol implementation by changing `'protocol'  => 'imap'`, to `'protocol'  => 'legacy-imap'`, in your configuration, or you can mimic the same behavior as the legacy protocol works by copy the message to trash, and delete the original.

Edit: LegacyProtocol relies on imap_* PHP methods, therefore you need imap PHP extension to be installed, probably with SSL support. Check your phpinfo() first.

2. Or use `copy()` and `delete()`